# Material-UI React and webpack tree shaking

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I decided to add [Material Ui React](https://material-ui.com/)to my app. I plan to use this minimally. So far I use it in one place

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

render() {return <TextField ... />
```

I am using the default CRA webpack configuration, and my assumption was that anything from the library that i do not use will not be added to my bundle. However when I use the bundle analyzer i see this.

[image: Bundle image]

Does Create-React-App not support tree shaking of dead code like I am imagining, or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: I've faces similar problems...I'm afraid tree shaking in webpack is just bad in general. It's even worse if you write something like `import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";`

Comment: How should I write it in order for it to be correct.  


I would like to use bits and pieces of Material-UI. But seems like a waste to have to import this heavy package for some text fields.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/ should help a bit

Comment: Another thing you could look into is using React.lazy, though I'm not sure if that's a good idea with base components like these